# in laravel SQLSTATE[HY000]: General eror: -625 validation error for column id, value "*** null ***" (SQL: insert into "users" ("name",) values (Павел)

Tags: laravel, firebird

I have the following error when registering in laravel.

Laravel version 8 
Database: Firebird \

I use the regular form. When registering the form, the following error appears:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -625 validation error for column id,
> value "*** null ***" (SQL: insert into "users" ("name", "email",
> "password", "updated_at", "created_at") values (Pavel, p@gmail.com ,
> $2y$10$hqno7.foR2zNuSZvaONfEOjEuXJRdVo2PxXhs9q6jgi.hduuf1kjg,
> 2023-01-01 11:03:22, 2023-01-01 11:03:22))

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: BTW, sting literals should be in apostrophes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be you aren't providing an ID, the id is null. An ID in an Firebird table shouldn't be autoincrement by default.

I suggest you to use UUID. I provide you the migration modified and what you should do in your model User:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

In your model User, you should add this changes:

```
protected $primaryKey='id';
public $incrementing=false;
protected $keyType='string';

protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function ($model) {
        if (empty($model->{$model->getKeyName()})) {
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Str::uuid()->toString();
        }
    });
}
```

You should be able to use it now without any problem

Comment: Thanks.The error Access level to App\Models\User comes out::$incrementing must be public (as in the Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User class)

Comment: You're welcome. You're right, I've updated the answer.

Comment: replaced with  public $incrementing;  and it worked